# Storing random number in old and new string

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is hard to explain; please ask me in comments if you cannot understand my question.

Please see the below code. First, I am generating random text from an array, then I have two `div` elements: `current` and `old` div. What I am trying to achieve is when start button is first pressed, any random text can be shown in `current` and `old` div. When the start button is pressed a second time, whichever text appeared in `old div` the first time should be shown in `current div` and any random text is shown in old div and loop goes on.

I tried to initialize `old` with 0 , but it is showing as `undefined` inside function.

```
<script>
    function randomFromTo(from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }
    var arrstring = new Array("images", "wallpaper", "photos", "vector",
        "designer", "wordpress", "jquery", "extjs", "scripting", "blogging", 
        "search", "tagging", "digital", "javascript", "server", "hosting",
        "social", "twitter", "graphic", "photoshop", "netbeans", "mysql",
        "apache", "iphone", "mobile", "android", "framework", "usability",
        "optimization", "interface", "developer");

    function random() {
        randomIndex = randomFromTo(0, arrstring.length - 1);
        return randomIndex;
    }

    var old = 0;
    function start() {
        var all = old;
        var old = random();
        $(".current").text(arrstring[all]);
        $(".old").text(arrstring[old]);
    }
</script>

<div class="current">old</div>
<div class="old">new</div>

<input type="button" onclick="start();" value="start" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're close! Just having some [variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) issues. Try something like this:

```
function start() {
  var all = random();
  $(".current").text(arrstring[all]);
  $(".old").text(arrstring[old]);
  old = all;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/zbSDC/

Answer (score 2):

HI guys i solved problem myself , I just removed var and it worked successfully

```
 function start()
    {
    all = old;
    old = random();
    $(".current").text(arrstring[all]);
    $(".old").text(arrstring[old]);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the same functionality in a cleaner way, but not polluting the global scope.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBR5c/)

```
function get_Random_String() {

    var arrstring = new Array("images", "wallpaper", "photos", "vector",
        "designer", "wordpress", "jquery", "extjs", "scripting", "blogging",
        "search", "tagging", "digital", "javascript", "server", "hosting",
        "social", "twitter", "graphic", "photoshop", "netbeans", "mysql",
        "apache", "iphone", "mobile", "android", "framework", "usability",
        "optimization", "interface", "developer");

    return arrstring[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrstring.length)];

}

function cycle_randoms() {
    $(".current").text($(".old").text());
    $(".old").text(get_Random_String());
}


$('input[value=start]').on('click', function () {
    cycle_randoms();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of global and local variable with same name..
only remove var to local variable..
It will give different meaning inside of that function..

```
    var old = 1; // Global
    function start() {
    var all = old; //local
    var old = random(); //local..
    ..}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Use jQuery built-in procedures.

you should use doc ready before applying changes to dom:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       /*ALL JS CODE HERE.*/
    });
```

try to use jQuery event listener:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   /*here is 'start' function */
});
```

optional: 
put all js code in `code.js` files, and put them inside your head section.